# Why my local website display Apache2 Test Page

Tags: apache-http-server, centos-6, httpd

I've installed `httpd`, `mysql` and `php` on my CentOS 6.4 server. I've setup Virtual host 80 and 443 for trien.abc

My client (windows 7) still displays Apache2 test page. Where did I go wrong?

My Apache config file containing the VirtualHost definition is located in: `/etc/httpd/vhosts/common/trien.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/testing.page
  ServerName trien.abc
  ServerAlias trien.abc
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/trien.error.log common
  LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %f" common
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/trien.access.log common
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/testing.page">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/testing.page` just has one file: `index.html`. The contents of the file is "Welcome, trien".

It can't display the contents of the file, instead it displays the Apache2 test page.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could happen because of many reasons..Some of the possible reasons are the following

- Check the selinux context of the index file. Try loading the page
  after setting selinux to permissive.
- Check permissions of the index file. It should be readable to others
- Have you restarted httpd after making changes?

  .
- Check the DirecoryIndex in your httpd.conf. In your case, it must be

> DirectoryIndex index.html

Please check your errorlog. paste it here if you cant troubleshoot.

Comment: "Check the selinux context of the index file. Try loading the page after setting selinux to permissive." -> i've disabled selinux. "Check permissions of the index file. It should be readable to others ."-> the permission of index.html is 0777. "Check the DirecoryIndex in your httpd.conf. In your case, it must be" -> maybe this cause from here. i've check in  /var/log/httpd/  there's no .error.log common at all. Do you know why?

Comment: Try accessing the absolute path of the page and keep posted here..like www.domainname.com/index.html

Comment: when i try this link: http://domainname.com/index.html => The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server. I don't know why...

Comment: You said you have an index.html in the document root. Now you are saying about index.php. What is the file actually?

Comment: html.. so sorry about this.

Comment: It means you have not placed the index file in the right location. Please check the Document Root path and the path by which you have your index file

Comment: i've just checked. Document Root path is like the path which index.html located.?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't updated your index.html/index.php or more accurately where you go when you go to the root of your seite - the stock one Apache 2 is the 'test' page. Update your document root to the appropriate location and it should work.

Don't forget to enable the virtualhosts and restart apache.

Comment: i've restart apache and it still doesn't work.